# How to remove the last space from end when using loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops

I am trying to make a program to print a list separated with space but I do not want the space in the last ?

I tried using string method but want more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Please show us what's you got - your attempts and where is failing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot to go on with the information you have provided but from what I understand may be this could help:-

```
l = ["Hello", "this", "is", "stackoverflow"]
n = len(l)

for i, ele in enumerate(l) :
    x = " "
    if i == n-1 :
        x = ""
    print(ele,end = x)
```